# Databricks execution failed with error state: InternalError, error message: failed to update run GlobalRunId(xx155,RunId(yy))

Tags: runtime-error, azure-data-factory, databricks, pipeline, azure-databricks

I'm facing this error during a pipeline run when using azure data factory to call a databricks notebook.  The notebook runs successsfully although the 'failed to update run GlobalRunId(xx,(Runid,yy))' message appears along with the databricks notebook status.  This is causing ADF to provide a false alert.

I tried searching for similar issues but this is really uncommon.  Would appreciate any help on this thanks.

I checked the databricks logs but there is nothing unusual relating to this error. Was hoping to find something useful

Comment: @data_engineerin10 are you trying to update the GlobalRunId within databricks?
Are you maintaining logs?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula nope Im not updating the globalrunid, looks like databricks internal error.  I checked the driver logs like stderror, stdout, log4j but nothing unusual

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below approach to see If I am getting the same error as you are getting at your end in Azure datafactory pipeline.

**The Below is my Pipeline:**

[image]

I tried to reproduce and see if I am encountering with the error **failed to update run GlobalRunId(xx(Runid,yy))'.**
However, As you can see the pipeline ran successfully.

- in my approach I am writing the Spark SQL tables to ADLS
  and then writing the data to the SQL table.

When I ran the pipeline I see no ERROR **failed to update runGlobalRunId(xx,(Runid,yy))'.**
The error **failed to update runGlobalRunId(xx,(Runid,yy))'** that you are getting It looks like databricks internal error.
Also make sure that all linked services and datasets used in the pipeline are valid and accessible.

Sometimes, the issue could be with linked services (like expired
credentials,Token expiry) will also lead pipeline run failures.

- Check if the pipeline has dependencies on other pipelines or datasets, make sure they are all configured correctly and available.
- Check the outputs of the activities in your pipeline. If an activity is failing retry the pipeline run to see if it resolves the issue.

As you mentioned the notebook runs successsfully although error states 'failed to update run GlobalRunId(xx,(Runid,yy))'
In this kind of scenarios please create a [support ticket](https://www.databricks.com/company/contact) with databricks
To get more details about the error and resolution to this situation.